# Cordova Image picker resize

Tags: cordova, ionic2

i am using ionic2.

I need image resize with cordova image picker.

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker
 npm install --save @ionic-native/image-picker

this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
      var arr = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

          this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + results[i];

          }
```

Here is my options

```
  const options  =   {
        maximumImagesCount: 3, // Android only since plugin version 2.1.1, default no limit
        quality: 90, // 0-100, default 100 which is highest quality
          // proportionally rescale image to this width, default no rescale
        maxWidth: 500, // photos only
        maxHeight: 500, // same for height
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,      
        correctOrientation: true,
        outputType: 1 // default .FILE_URI
    }
```

But selected images are does not resize.

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its because `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` do not exist as properties.
The correct properties are `width` and `height`

Your options should be like this, i also removed some properties that are not supported by imagepicker:

```
const options  =   {
        maximumImagesCount: 3, 
        quality: 90, 
        width: 500, 
        height: 500
    }
```

You can also have a look on their documentation https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

Comment: @ANISUNDAR check my edited answer, the options object should look like this

Comment: @Akis.I select multiple images these images are same height.How can i do this.pls help me..i tried to this many way.But still i not get slutions